# Run a function on second click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and have inline buttons on my forms. The first click will enable the textfield to edit. The second click will save the change via ajax.

html

```
<fieldset class="form-horizontal input-append">                
    <legend>Evelyn Jones <span class=" badge badge-important">Account Locked</span></legend>                    
    <div class="alert alert-success" style="display: block;">Success Confirmation.</div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email Address</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input name="ctl00$ctl00$PortalContent$PortalContent$txtEmailAddress" type="text" value="test" id="txtEmailAddress" class="aspNetDisabled span3" disabled="disabled">
            <a id="lnkEditEmailAddress" class="btn" data-attr="edit"><i class="icon-ok icon-edit"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="txtUserName">Username</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input name="ctl00$ctl00$PortalContent$PortalContent$txtUserName" type="text" value="test" id="txtUserName" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled span3">
            <a id="lnkEditUsername" class="btn" data-attr="edit" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$PortalContent$PortalContent$lnkEditUsername','')"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
            <a id="lnkEmailUsername" class="btn" data-attr="email" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$PortalContent$PortalContent$lnkEmailUsername','')"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail"></label>
         <div class="controls">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button class="btn">Unlock Account</button>
                    <button class="btn">Reset Password</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</fieldset>
```

jquery

```
$('.alert').hide();

$('.controls a[data-attr="edit"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();        $(this).toggleClass("btn-primary");
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass("icon-white").toggleClass("icon-edit").addClass('icon-ok');
    $(this).siblings('input[type=text]').attr('disabled', function(idx, oldAttr) {
        return !oldAttr;
    });
});

function success() {
    $('.alert').fadeIn();
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcDrY/)

Currently the input field toggles as I'd like. How can I call the success function only on the second click of the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?, I'm checking the class that you're adding to the button:

```
if($(this).hasClass("btn-primary")) {
    success();
} else {
    hideSuccess();
}
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcDrY/1/)

Comment: good grief easy enough, I was too close to the solution.  Thanks, nice and simple.